# removeattr scroll-sel and Add atriv

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like a Javascript for remove

```
<ul class="selection-list sel-scroll sel-items js-items-unchecked">
```

REMOVE only (sel-scroll)

And then add this code below that

This code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="js/jScrollPane.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jScrollPane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        $('#pane1').jScrollPane({showArrows:false,scrollbarWidth:10, scrollbarMargin:20});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery. Therefore you can do:

```
$('#elementID').removeClass('sel-scroll');
```

Also look into:

```
$('.sel-scroll').removeClass('sel-scroll');
```

Comment: Dont work, this code is in a lightbox, maybe that's the problem

Comment: Did the `$('.sel-scroll').removeClass('sel-scroll');` not work? Really surprised as that should remove the sel-scroll from every element.

Comment: instead of deleting it, I tried to make a document.body.scrollTop = 40000
 
but I only work on the main page, in the checkbox did not work

Comment: <ul class="selection-list sel-scroll sel-items js-items-unchecked" id="yui_3_11_1_1377272630571_3148">

The #elementID is yui_3_11_1_1377272630571_3148??